# Apple script - How is an app registered?

Tags: applescript

I have written an Apple Script file which stopped working after I have changed the used application from being an actual directory to a link. This change was made to ease changing versions of the application.

How can I reassociate the link as an application so that the script starts the right file?
Currently I always receive the error "Unknown application" when running the script.

Edit: I am starting the application manually now. Thus it has nothing to do with starting

Comment: Would you post a minimal test case?

Answer (score 0):

Apple registers all applications when you run them, maybe starting that application might help.